# PHP - Edit XML using DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am using simple PHP script which creates XML.

XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article id="1"><published>05/01/2015 04:32:36</published><author position="writer">John Stewart</author>
```

Nothing special right? Yea and after that i write another PHP script which try to add second article to XML.

The code looks like:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();

$dom->load("articles.xml");

$article=$dom->createElement("article");
$article->setAttribute("id", 2);
$published=$dom->CreateElement("published");
$publishedDate=$dom->createTextNode(date("d/m/Y h:i:s", strtotime("tomorrow")));
$published->appendChild($publishedDate);
$article->appendChild($published);
$author=$dom->createElement("author");
$author->setAttribute("position", "writer");
$authorName=$dom->createTextNode("Ivan Dimov");
$author->appendChild($authorName);
$article->appendChild($author);
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($article);

$dom->save("articles.xml");
```

I'm probably blind because this code looks good for me, but generate XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article id="1"><published>05/01/2015 04:32:36</published><author position="writer">John Stewart</author>
<article id="2"><published>06/01/2015 12:00:00</published><author position="writer">Ivan Dimov</author></article></article>
```

So in general, it adds new `<article>` before it end old one , and now XML have twice end article tag at the end.

Can someone help me to find the correct way how to do that? If you find a bit time to explain me what was wrong it would be awesome.

Thank you all for reading

Comment: Note you have `article` and `articleS` tags at the end. The second one has a trailing `s`.

Comment: Really good point @fedorqui , anyway now i changed it in XML file before edit. But i still need to change the way how this PHP edit XML becuase now i have </article> at the end twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a nested element, whereas you just need a new one in the same level of the first. So just use

```
$dom->appendChild($article);
```

instead of

```
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($article);
```

I tried it with your script and I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles id="1"><published>05/01/2015 04:23:18</published><author position="writer">John Stewart</author></articles>
<articles id="2"><published>06/01/2015 12:00:00</published><author position="writer">Ivan Dimov</author></articles>
```

So the full code would be:

```
<?php

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("articles.xml");

$article=$dom->createElement("articles");
...
$article->appendChild($author);
//$dom->documentElement->appendChild($article); // commented
$dom->appendChild($article);                    // the good one

$dom->save("articles.xml");
```

---

Info taken from [DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php#refsect1-domdocument.createelement-examples) in php.net in the first full example: *Example #1 Creating a new element and inserting it as root*

```
// Example #1 Creating a new element and inserting it as root
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$element = $dom->createElement('test', 'This is the root element!');

// We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
$dom->appendChild($element);

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: You are RIGHT! Thank you mate. Will mark this answer as correct as soon as I will be able ..

Comment: But now you have an XML document with more than one root/top-level element.

Comment: @VolkerK yep, not a very canonical XML but apparently it is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Andurit ah now I see you had further questions you commented in the other answer. No, just proceed and accept the answer that helped you the most. Too bad I didn't see it before. In the future, try to keep asking in the main question, instead of in comments.

Comment: Right now i make it work, it looks like http://pastebin.com/duSTKKfY, not sure if it's 100% correct for a code one and security and things like that but looks it atelast works

Comment: @Andurit nice! As VolkerK comments in his answer, the way to go would be to have a proper hierarchy instead of two top level `<article>` items. But you are the one handling the code, so just cross check if the generated XML is good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you had that article/articles error in your original post, could it be that you've changed an existing code example that worked on a document like

```
<articles>
  <article id="1">...</article>
...
  <article id="n">...</article>
</articles>
```

?
According to the xml specification an xml document has exactly one document element, not more.

```
<?php
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadxml( getData() );
$article = newArticle($doc);
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($article);
echo $doc->savexml();



function newArticle(DOMDocument $doc)
{
    $article=$doc->createElement("article");
    $article->setAttribute("id", 2);
    $published=$doc->CreateElement("published");
    $publishedDate=$doc->createTextNode(date("d/m/Y h:i:s", strtotime("tomorrow")));
    $published->appendChild($publishedDate);
    $article->appendChild($published);
    $author=$doc->createElement("author");
    $author->setAttribute("position", "writer");
    $authorName=$doc->createTextNode("Ivan Dimov");
    $author->appendChild($authorName);
    $article->appendChild($author);
    return $article;
}

function getData() {
return <<< eox
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
    <article id="1">
        <published>05/01/2015 04:32:36</published>
        <author position="writer">John Stewart</author>
    </article>
</articles>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
  <article id="1">
    <published>05/01/2015 04:32:36</published>
    <author position="writer">John Stewart</author>
  </article>
  <article id="2">
    <published>06/01/2015 12:00:00</published>
    <author position="writer">Ivan Dimov</author>
  </article>
</articles>
```

Comment: It's still possible the OP wants to include the list of articles as a fragment/entity in a/another xml document - makes appending elements easier. In that case the article elements could be a "top-level" sequence. But then the xml declaration has to be removed.

Comment: Looks i didn't know few things about XML, cool to know @VolkerK, actually perfect example as well, but somehow i can't make it save just print. (i remove that "echo" before save) Can you find a bit more time to help me with let your perfect example work for me?

Thanks
p.s. Already have thumb up from me.

Comment: you have to revert to ->save() instead of ->savexml(). Same as with loadxml()/load(). .oO( wouldn't it be cool if load()/save() took a stream parameter instead of having separate loadxml()/savexml() methods? )

Comment: You should never have multiple top level element nodes in a document, that's what a document fragment is for.